# In Mobile suit Gundam ZZ, how was Judau able to control the separated parts of his Gundam?

Tags: gundam

I believe it was episode 47 when Judau battles Hammon Karn's Qubeley. Hammon manages to get hold of the Gundam Double Zeta. In order to break free, Judau separates his Gundam (it has three components, each with its own cockpit). Then there is some nonsense about the two leaving their mobile suits, Hammon with a gun and Judau with some metal rod. When Judau returns to his Gundam, he is able to use his Newtype powers to take control of the parts of his Gundam and reassemble them.

Now, in other instances where Newtype powers resonate with the pilot's mobile suit and result in some kind of physical action, it is attributed to the Psycommu. However, this is introduced to Federation and Aeug suits until the 2nd Neo Zeon War (this was the first) and double Zeta Gundam definitely did not have a Psycommu system.

There are two other instances I found where similar occurrences happened. One was when Amuro prevented Axis from crashing into Earth in what was to become known as the Axis shock. The other was when Banagher was able to link the Garencieres with the Nahel Argama. However, these two instances involve Gundams with Psycommu systems installed.

What explanation for Judau's abilities are there? Does this supersede the realm of science fiction? Would this be a deus ex machina?

**Edit**: I believe my initial assumptions when asking my questions were a bit incorrect. The Psycommu system was around since the 1 year war, present in several mobile armors including but not limited to Lalah's Elmeth and Char's Zeong. In Char's Deleted Affair, it is incorporated greatly into the mobile suit designs on Axis and eventually led to the creation of the Qubeley. The Psycho frame on the other hand wasn't introduced until the 2nd Neo Zeon War. I had the two systems confused. It was the Psycho frame which allowed the Axis shock to occur and allowed Banagher to get the Garencieres into space. However, the question still stands, How did Judau manage to reassemble his Gundam which lacked the psycho frame and psycommu?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I researched it was a combination of plew's spirit and Psycho Frame of Qubeley, but still no clear data can be found on this, but as a reference we can see in the final episode of Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam, Kamille fights with spirits of his friends to destroy Paptimus Scirocco's mobile suit.

Comment: That actually seems like a reasonable explanation. I remember towards the end of Char's Counter Attack,Chan Agi tries to bring a tiny piece of Psycho frame to Amuro, indicating the mere proximity of the technology is enough to enhance Newtype abilities.